# Airline Ticketing

Tags: web-development, ecommerce, api, open-source

How does airline ticketing works. Is there any software which we can integrate in client's existing CMS website to allow visitors to book airplane tickets through there existing system.

Answer (score 1):

I never implement such system but a quick search on Google give you few examples:

- [Is there any API for getting flight fare (on SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680408/is-there-any-api-for-getting-flight-fare)
- [Cleartrip Flights API Reference](http://www.cleartrip.com/api/docs/air-api/)
- [Wego Flights API documentation](http://www.wego.com/api/flights/docs)